# can we unselect the selected radio button by clicking again

Tags: flex3

is there any way we can unselect the selected radio button by clicking again

Answer (score 1):

No.

A radio button, by definition, is one of a set of mutually exclusive choices.

You have two options.

1. Rework you choices so that they can be presented as a series of checkboxes.
2. Add a "clear" button/checkbox (not recommended), or "Non of the above" choice.

However, having all your radio buttons cleared means that your program is in an undefined state, not something you want.

Comment: thanks Chris, but i have radio button inside grid and i can select multiple radio at a time but if we want some of them unchecked is there any way ... may be in JS ???

Comment: @Priya - then it's not really a radio button? can you post a screen shot of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason for this is a radio button chooses one of a set of options. If you could click to unset what would be the option you chose?

the point of a radio button is to make sure you make a choice and not leave the backing variable undefined.

Comment: thanks Mark, but i have radio button inside grid and i can select multiple radio at a time but if we want some of them unchecked is there any way ... may be in JS ???

Comment: As noted that is not a radio button